# как обрезать строку в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно сохранить результат echo в какую либо переменную. Как это можно сделать?

> echo "$file" | cut -d "/" -f5

Ps: само echo не важно сделал как единственный получающийся вариант пробовал сохранять в переменную почему-то не выходит

Comment: Почитай про перенаправление стандартных потоков ввода вывода через операции "<" и ">"

Comment: `var=$(команда)`

Comment: ну или так можно `var="\`команда\`"`

Comment: А вообще, судя по примеру, почитайте про `dirname`, `basename`.